# Apple password verification showing weird characters

Tags: macos

I recently had to reload Yosemite on my Macbook Pro Retina (Mid 2014)
and after booting it up this morning and allowing a application to run, my password box looks like this.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Font Database is corrupted, you can rebuild it. (NOTE: make backup before performing this)

```
sudo atsutil databases -remove
```

And then repair permissions:

```
sudo diskutil repairPermissions /
```

After it's finished restart your machine.

Answer (score 3):

That looks like font corruption. I'd run the "standard toolkit"

- Fix permissions, Verify & if necessary Repair disk, using Disk Utility.
- Reset Home folder permissions & ACLs using [OnyX](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html)  - Maintenance tab/permissions, tick the box at the top then Execute.
- Update to [or re-apply if already up to date] 10.10.5 using the [10.10.5 combo update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1832), not the delta from App Store.